# Running apps on Genymotion over local network

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I have two machines running on the same network. I use one machine for development and the other has various android emulators.

I need to run apps on the emulator running on the other pc from the development pc. Something like the run command in Android studio should make the app install in Genymotion running on the other pc.

Possible? Any ideas ?

Comment: The only idea I have is to forward port 5555 on the target PC to the emulator using VirtualBox virtual network adapter. You'll have to root your Genymotion emulators to be able to use apps like ADB Over Wifi. This comes more complicated once you want to run multiple emulators on this machine.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible.
You first need to expose your Genymotion devices to the local network. For this, create all the device you want to run on the dedicated computer. Then open VirtualBox locally and for each device do this:

1. Open the Settings > Network tab
2. Open the "Adapter 2"
3. Change the "Attached to" option to "Bridged Adapter" (by default it is set to NAT)
4. Click OK

Then you need to get the local IP of the device. You can get it by running this command:

```
adb shell "ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr(\$2,6)}' | awk 'NR==2'"
```

When all these things are done, come back to your development PC. Open a terminal and type for each of your remote Genymotion devices:

```
adb connect <DEVICE_IP>
```

This way, you will connect your local adb deamon to the remote devices.

You are now able to control your remote Genymotion devices as if they were local. You can run `adb install` to install APKs remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively download [WiFi ADB - Debug Over Air](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) apk. Install it in you running genymotion emulator. 
Turn on Adb connect that's it.

Not you can find ip:5555 on emulator app running screen. 
Using this ip you can connect any pc running in same local network.

Answer (score 0):

Being simple "try port forwarding". I have used [TCPPortForward](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/TCP-Port-Forwarding.shtml) tool to do that.

You can do this:

1. Get IP Address and Port of Genymotion Emulator:  `adb devices`
2. Get IP Address of assigned to you device over Lan:   `ipconfig`
3. Forward the `<EMULATOR_IP:PORT>` to `<DEVICE_LAN_IP:PORT>` using any tool like [TCPPortForward](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/TCP-Port-Forwarding.shtml).
    Here is see a screenshot of TCPPortForward [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVmMf.png)

Finally, on remote device run

```
adb connect <DEVICE_IP>:<PORT>
```

Also you can map different ports for multiple emulators from same LAN IP.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [WiFi adb app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) in the genemotion and use its url to your system.